# Task do not assign to exectuor after spark speculation take effect in SparkStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a SparkStreaming application reading message from kafka, all the task process data with locality of process_local.
The speculation take effect and rerun task in other executor when a task pending in executor 0 (see the picture below)

task pending img : https://imgchr.com/i/FWWMDS

But I find out that no task will assign to executor 0 after speculation take effect, and the data locality change form process_local to any, which cause more time to shechdule task

executor lost img : https://imgchr.com/i/FWW3Nj

cluster executor info img : https://imgchr.com/i/FWWY3q

some config:

```
spark.speculation.interval  500ms
spark.scheduler.mode    FIFO
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition   100
spark.locality.wait 1s
spark.defalut.parallelism   6
```

How can I make task assign to executor 0 again and recover the data locality from any to process_local?

Why task will not assign to executor 0 any more?

Comment: I don't konw the cause why task pending yet, but I found a solution, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18761

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is kafka consumer lib version used in program, use kafka v0.10.2.1 instead,see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20780